# "The TOP h-cobordism theorem without surgery??"

Tags: manifolds, topological-manifolds

Kirby and Siebenmann's book on topological manifolds contains the following intriguing passage on page 141:

[image]

I believe no such proof has been discovered, though I'd be happy to be corrected on that.

> Were there any serious attempts to find this still undiscovered proof? If so, what new techniques did they introduce and did they obtain interesting intermediate results?

If there were serious attempts, maybe their failure can be taken as evidence against the plausibility of the existence of an undiscovered simple proof of the annulus theorem.

> Is it still believed to be plausible that there is an undiscovered simple proof of the annulus theorem?

Comment: [Kirby's proof](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kirby/papers/Kirby%20-%20On%20the%20annulus%20conjecture%20-%20MR0192481.pdf) does not qualify?

Comment: It has an additional planar assumption. It is from 1966, while  Kirby-Siebenmann is from 1977, so the above passage was written a decade after that paper.

Comment: When Kirby finally proved the annulus conjecture in [1969](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kirby.pdf), he reduced it to the "hauptvermutung for tori," which is false, but true after after passing to a cover, which is sufficient. Chapman, using a theorem of Edwards proved a variant of the torus theorem [without surgery](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368391). Is that sufficient?